# Directory Listing (ls) error ONLY in port 22 (SFTP)

Tags: ssh, firewall, port, sftp

Using **SFTP** I suddenly get this result:

```
Status: Connecting to 64.207.146.82...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "root@64.207.146.82" 22
Command:    Pass: *********
Status: Connected to 64.207.146.82
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    pwd
Response:   Current directory is: "/root"
Command:    ls
Status: Listing directory /root
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I tested in **Cyberduck**, **FileZila** and **Terminal**, same result. I can login but once I get to the point when: **Directory Listing** it freezes (no answer).

I can access using FTP (**port 21**) with a different user, the problem is that I cannot update any of the files (I have been working as root).

Tested in 3 computers, same result in my office. However, I tested at home and it works (so I guess is not a problem with the Hosting provider).

Doing some debugging from ssh:

```
ssh -vv root@domain.com
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to domain.com [64.207.146.82] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 128/256
debug2: bits set: 543/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'domain.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/Admin/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug2: bits set: 508/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Admin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@domain.com's password: 
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to domain.com ([64.207.146.82]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Fri Dec 21 19:55:45 2012 from ip5-222-15-186.ct.co.cr
############################################################
                     (mt) shortcuts
############################################################

To see your Plesk password, type: p

To rebuild your Apache/Web Server configuration, type: web

To rebuild your Qmail/Mail Server configuration, type: mchk

To see your Qmail/Mail Server queue, type: q

To completely restart your Qmail/Mail server, type: r

To connect to your MySQL server as admin, type: my

To apply the latest Plesk microupdates, type: up

To get rid of these messages/aliases, edit your /root/.bash_profile

[root@domain ~]#
```

**SOLUTION**:

Once you login/connect with the server using SSH:

```
p link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
3: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue 
    link/void 
[root@domian ~]# ip link set eth0 mtu 1400
SIOCSIFMTU: No such device
[root@domian ~]# ip link set venet0 mtu 1400
[root@domian ~]# ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
3: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1400 qdisc noqueue 
    link/void 
[root@domian ~]#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your network behind a PPPoE connection? Do you also have this problem if you try to download a large (more than a kilobyte) file with scp?

If so, then it looks like you may be having MTU size issues. Common problem with DSL networks, and if you google for "pppoe mtu" you will find plenty of hits. Cisco, for example, has a [rather good explanation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk175/tk15/technologies_tech_note09186a0080093bc7.shtml#topic1).

The short, simplified version is that when a client and a server negotiate a maximum MTU size they negotiate it based on their own direct connectivity (normally LAN), and when there is a link with a smaller maximum allowed MTU size in between them (the PPPoE link), the bigger packets start to get lost.

Normally this is solved with:

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o ppp+ \
    -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN \
    -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

**Update**: As it seems that there is no PPP connection anywhere on the way, you could try lowering the interface MTU on the server just as a test, so you know if that is the problem. For example, you can check the current value with:

```
ip link show
```

Look for "MTU" in the output. And to **temporarily** lower it (assuming `eth0` is your interface), try

```
ip link set eth0 mtu 1400
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation. My network is using a DHCP (not PPPoE), Directory Listing doesn't show any anything, so I can't download or copy any files right now using port 22. The changes you propose for iptables are for the network (not for my computer) right?

Comment: @82din, I updated with advice to lower the MTU on the server, to see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you @chutz , I included your solution in my question.